# Cannot listen to pusher private channel events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, leaflet, pusher

I am trying to design a chat application where I am trying to pass messages throuhh Pusher's private channels for real time delivery.

I am working with [Smart Admin Theme's ajax version](http://192.241.236.31/themes/preview/smartadmin/1.5/ajaxversion/#ajax/dashboard.html) and I am working with the chat UI plugin that ships with the theme itself.

Basically I have Mapbox map and using Leaflet I have placed a lot of markers on the map, where each marker is a user.

So basically when the user is logged in, he can view the other users on the map and when he clicks the map, this code executes:

```
// Binding the marker on click event to bring up the chat
marker.on('click', function(){
    var chatboxId = 'private-' + currentUser.id + '-' + user.id;
    chatboxManager.addBox(chatboxId, {
        first_name: user.first_name,
        last_name: user.last_name,
    });

    // Creating a new chatbox
    $('#' + chatboxId).chatbox({
        messageSent: function(id, user, message){
            this.boxManager.addMsg('Me', message);

            splittedId = id.split('-');

            $.ajax({
                url: '/messages',
                method: 'post',
                type: 'json',
                data: {
                    receiver_id: splittedId[2],
                    body: message
                }
            });
        }
    });

    // Initializing pusher and authenticating the private channel
    var pusher = new Pusher('082bab423e2a8be3da2a', {
        authTransport: 'jsonp',
        authEndpoint: '/pusher/auth'
    });

    // Subscribing to the channel where the name of the channel is private-senderId-receiverId
    var chat = pusher.subscribe('private-' + user.id + '-'  + currentUser.id);
    console.log(chat);
    chat.bind('message', function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

This code generates a new chatbox for the user that was clicked on the map. At this point pusher is also initialized and it contacts '/pusher/auth' for authentication for the private channel.

The authentication is working fine. I know this because pusher returns a token as it is supposed to in JSON. Then I bind the channel variable to listen to "message" event but I cannot listen to the new messages on the channel.

Further more when I tried to `console.log(chat)` (the private channel), it outputs this in the console:

> ```
> Object { callbacks: Object, global_callbacks: Array[0], failThrough:
> b/<(), name: "private-1-1", pusher: Object, subscribed: false }
> ```

The subscribed is false for some reason. What am I doing wrong? I am sure I am missing something small somewhere and I have been at this for more that 2 hours now. Can anybody point out what am I missing?

**Edit : Server side route for authentication**

```
Route::get('/pusher/auth', function(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request, \App\User $user){
    $data = $request->all();

    $explodedChannel = explode('-' ,$data['channel_name']);

    if($user->currentUser()->id == $explodedChannel[2]){
        $pusher = new \Pusher(
            getenv('PUSHER_PUBLIC'),
            getenv('PUSHER_PRIVATE'),
            getenv('PUSHER_APPID')
        );
        echo $pusher->socket_auth($data['channel_name'], $data['socket_id']);
    }
    else{
        return response()->json('Forbidden', 403);
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you please provide the output of the [Pusher JavaScript logging](https://pusher.com/docs/debugging#pusher_logging)?

Comment: @leggetter I was not aware of this. I will look into this and update my question. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

edit your server side code where echo auth response like this:

edit this

```
 echo $pusher->socket_auth($data['channel_name'], $data['socket_id']);
```

to

```
        $auth= $pusher->socket_auth(Input::get('channel_name'), Input::get('socket_id'));
        $callback = str_replace('\\', '', $_GET['callback']);
        header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
        echo($callback . '(' . $auth . ');');
        return;
```